# LRU best way to do a quick implementation in java

Tags: java, algorithm, caching, lru

I want to construct a quick LRU cache.
Is this kind of solution is a good way to do this ?
And what about the synchronization ?

There’s a protected method called removeEldestEntry. This method is called when items are being added to the map. The default implementation just returns false. But i can subclass LinkedHashMap and override this method to check whether a maximum size has been reached, then just return true. The LinkedHashMap will find the oldest entry via the linked list and boot it before adding a new entry.

```
public class MyLRUMap<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V> {
private int maxCapacity;

public MyLRUMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, int maxCapacity) {
super(initialCapacity, loadFactor, true);
this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
}

@Override
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry<K,V> eldest) {
return size() >= this.maxCapacity;
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the recommended way to do it although it might be best to do `size() > this.maxCapacity` instead of `>=`

Comment: Is it because the removeEldest method is called after than new element is inserted ?
If i do >=, my map will maintain maxCapacity -1 as its size ?

Comment: Correct, according to the Javadoc, removedEldest is called AFTER put() and putAll()

Answer (score 2):

i would like to recommend guava/cachebuilder for this

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is mentioned in the book “Java Generics and Collections”
[here](http://codeidol.com/java/javagenerics/Maps/Implementing-Map/)